# Adding libraries to MonoDevelop C++ projects

Tags: c++, linux, static-libraries, monodevelop

How can I add `-lX11`, -`lopenal` and `-lalut` libraries to a C++ Project created in MonoDevelop IDE in linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Code Generation tab of the Code Generation section of the project options has the option to manually add custom/extra compiler options and linker options.

Also you can add libraries via the Libraries tab (example below is from a ncurses project):

Project Options : Code Generation : Libraries tab:

[image]

Comment: it seems I should omit the preceding `-l`. Unlike QtCreator.

Comment: Correct, on the Libraries type, it is just the library name, no compiler/linker directives. On the Code Generation tab, you would provide compiler and linker options just as you would on the cmd-line.